# Django: Creating/Copying/Removing DBs dynamically

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, orm

I know that I can employ `using()` to select a DB that is defined in `settings.py` for operations such as:

```
User.objects.using('users_db').get(id=5).delete()
```

The problem is that I need to dynamically create/copy/delete several different DBs while the server is running (without restarting the server). So that I can change the DB configuration in `settings.py` and select the active DB in my code by employing the `using()`.

**Update:** Please notice that since we have access to the DB settings through `connections.databases` after importing `connections` from `django.db`, the main problem is not how to define DBs in the `setting.py`. I am searching for such django ORM commands that can create/copy/delete a Database.

Comment: Django may not the right solution for this problem. In other words, to solve this problem - you'll have to step out of the ORM and "manually" write your DB code that connects to the other DBs and then execute queries. Consider offloading this part to separate (vanilla) Python script which you call from Django.

Comment: Why do you need to change your database like this on the fly?

Comment: The reason that I need to create/copy/delete databases is that there are several collections of data that are isolated from each other. the user may decide to select a special set of data and do the processes for them, then he can create new ones/copy and alter previous ones and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There are **two** ways to deal with this.

1. You can use postgresql and use json field to store your informations. 
   In this case you can use all django features and it is the recommended way to do what you trying to achieve.
   Source - [Jsonfield Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield)
2. You can use mongodb and create dynamic databases. But you cannot use Django ORM with this. ( There is an django-mongodb engine - [Django-mongodb-engine](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
   but this won't be useful for creating and deleting dynamic databases). So you should use [Pymongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/python/client/) and write wrapper functions around it create dynamic databases.

Comment: I can not understand the relationship between creating/copying/deleting databases with having a JSON field. @subha.py

Comment: If you want to insert dynamic data like a dictionary you should go for option 1, else go for option 2

Comment: I want to create new complete DATABASEs/delete some existing DATABASEs completely and I prefer to work in MySQL.

Comment: That is very tough to achieve and is not a feasible approach if you have deadlines.

Comment: And what about if I don't have any deadline? @subha.py